# How can I add an order table to my SQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have a "products" table and a "users" table in my SQL database.

I would like to add an order table that has 4 columns: Order ID, order status, order user which is the ID of the user who passed the order, and order item which is the product(s) that the user has passed.

So I wrote this MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE 'order' (
order_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
order_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
order_user INT NOT NULL,
order_item INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_OrderUser FOREIGN KEY (order_user) REFERENCES users(usersId),
CONSTRAINT FK_OrderItem FOREIGN KEY (order_item) REFERENCES products(item_id)
)
```

And I got an error that says:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''order' (
> order_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
> order_stat...' at line 1

What should I do?

Comment: The single quotes around `order` are not corret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is really a typo.  *But* I want to strongly discourage your from naming a table `order`.  That is a SQL keywrod.  Just say "no"!

A very simple method is to use the plural, `orders`.  After all, it contains more than one order:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    order_user INT NOT NULL,
    order_item INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_OrderUser FOREIGN KEY (order_user) REFERENCES users(usersId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_OrderItem FOREIGN KEY (order_item) REFERENCES products(item_id)
);
```

Now, this works if an order has only one item.  Presumably that is not the case and you really want *two* tables, one for orders and one for products in an order:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    order_user INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_OrderUser FOREIGN KEY (order_user) REFERENCES users(usersId)
);

CREATE TABLE order_products (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_order_items_order_id FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(order_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_order_items_product_id FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
);
```

Note that I adjusted the terminology to just use `product` rather than mixing up `item` and `product`.